# How probable is this, assuming that we are deliberately trying to get 12345 next to each other with the first 5 tiles clicked?

Tags: probability

The game is called minesweeper, where you click on a tile and it reveals how many mines are around the tile. If there are 0, it reveals all tiles around the 0 tile which are also 0 until it reveals a number higher than 0 on the circumference of what has been revealed. I have absolutely no clue how to calculate the probability of the event depicted in the image but maybe one of you guys feels like solving it.

There are $99$ mines on a $16 \times 30$ field and we are also assuming that the mines have been placed randomly and the entire field is already set in place before the first tile has been opened.

[image: minesweeper_image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure everyone is familiar with the rules of the game you are talking about.  Regardless of the details, I expect that simulation is the way to go.  It can be analytically difficult to incorporate all the rules of a game into some sensible combinatorial formula.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It's also not clear (to me, at least) what event you are speaking of.  Do you set out with a particular block of $5$ you intend to test or do you have some strategy in mind?  Are you requiring that the block be in order? That is, would $25314$ be a win or a loss?

Comment: To be fair... depending on the implementation this scenario is outright impossible.  Most implementations of minesweeper (*notably including the official ones*) are such that the first click will *always* be a zero, thus revealing a region including all those adjacent to the zero (*and further adjacent to any additional zeroes revealed in this way*) and not just a single square.  The map is not generated until that first click.